# Migration from javax.jms to jbossMessaging

Tags: jboss, jms, messaging

I am working for a migration project in which jms code is written using stadard code javax.jms and running on jboss-3.x.

Now we are migrating to jboss-4.3, which support Jboss Messaging(JBM), I want to what kind of changes i have to do in JMS code.

Please help me in this Regard.

Thanks and Regards,
Rahul Aahir.

Answer (score 1):

JBossAS 3.x uses JBossMQ as its JMS implementation. JBossAS 4.3 uses JBossMessaging as its JMS implementation.

Both are JMS implementations, and therefore you use the JMS API (i.e. `javax.jms`) with both. Your code should not (in theory) require any rewriting.

However, the way your configure things is very different between JBossMQ and JBossMessaging. I can only suggest you go and read [the user guide for JBossMessaging](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/userguide-1.4.0.SP3/html/index.html), it contains some information on how to migrate.

Note that JBossAS 4.3 contains JBossMessaging 1.4.0, not the later 2.x versions.